# How to find all empty files and folders in a specific directory including files which just look empty but are not?

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, directory, search

Let's say that in my folder `~/list` I have a large amount of folders each with their own sub-folders and sub-sub-folders etc, and there are lots of files almost on each level. However some of these files and folders are empty, so how can I recursively search through them all to find the empty files and folders? And then have them displayed in a list of file locations so that I know where each one is (it should also be clear which is a file and which is a folder because not all files have file extensions). I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

**Please note** that it would also be very useful if it would also tell me if a file looked empty but wasn't (for instance if it had spaces or linebreaks in it or something). And would differentiate between a *real* empty file and one that just looks empty in the output.

Comment: An empty file, is a file with no characters? (could be spaces, linebreaks  and tabs)?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Well, previously I was thinking just files which are 0 bytes, but now that you mention it, someone might have been crazy enough to give me a file with spaces or linebreaks or something, so I would like to detect those too, but I would like for the output to differentiate between an actual empty file, and one that just looks empty.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From `man find`

```
    -empty File is empty and is either a regular file or a directory.
```

So to find both empty files and directories it is sufficient to do

```
find ~/lists -empty
```

To indicate the type, you could use the `%y` output format specifier

```
          %y     File's type (like in ls -l), U=unknown type (shouldn't happen)
```

e.g.

```
find ~/lists -empty -printf '%y %p\n'
```

or make use of an external program like `ls`, which includes a `--classify` option

```
    -F, --classify
          append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

i.e.

```
find ~/lists -empty -exec ls -Fd {} \;
```

---

If your definition of 'empty' is expanded to include files containing only whitespace characters, then it becomes more complicated - and more computationally intensive, since now you need to actually open at least any non-empty files and examine their contents. The most efficient way I can think of off the top of my head would be something like

```
find ~/list \( -empty -o \( -type f -a ! -exec grep -qm1 '[^[:blank:]]' {} \; \) \) -exec ls -Fd {} \;
```

(either empty, OR a file AND grep does not detect at least one non-blank character). Likely there is a better way though.

Comment: Sorry, I missed something out, please look at the edited version of my question. It shouldn't be too much to add.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work with softlinks. It probably uses the size of the softlink instead of the size of the destination and a softlink itself is never empty since it must have a path to another file (it's at least 1 character).

Answer (score 16):

From `~/list` folder:

```
find . -empty -type d
```

for listing empty directories and

```
find . -empty -type f
```

for listing empty files.

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'if [ `cat "{}" |wc -w` -eq 0 ]; then echo "file - {}";fi' \; -or -empty -exec bash -c "echo dir - {}" \;
```

for listing empty folders and files including whitespaces and empty lines

Comment: And will this recursively list sub-folders and their contents as well?

Comment: this will recursively show empty files and folders

Comment: Sorry, I missed something out, please look at the edited version of my question. It shouldn't be too much to add.

Comment: `[ \`grep -c [[:alnum:]] "{}"\` -eq 0 ]` will let through files containing only characters not in the `[A-Za-z0-9]` set.

Comment: @kos - probably graph instead alnum will do the job

Comment: `[:alnum:]` would let through files containing only characters not in the `[A-Za-z0-9]` and `[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~]` set. The only correct way to do that check would be checking whether every character is in the `[:space:]` set, or checking whether a character not in the `[:space:]` set is found like steeldriver did.