# Deleting empty while keeping non empty 4KB files in Ubuntu

Tags: files, rsync, du

I have a folder that contains hundreds of thousands of small .txt files of size 4kb. Some of them are totally empty while others are not. However, they all show the same size 4kb since this is the minimum block size configured. Is there a way to massively delete the empty ones but keep the non empty? Doing an

```
rsync --remove-sent-files -rv --min-size=4kb
```

removes everything.

Thank you

Comment: Possibly related: [How to find all empty files and folders in a specific directory including files which just look empty but are not?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719912/how-to-find-all-empty-files-and-folders-in-a-specific-directory-including-files)

Comment: Hello, the files are not empty they contain hidden characters like line breaks etc. so they have a size.

Comment: ... yes - hence *"look empty but they are not"*

Comment: Hello, the solution proposed in the SO link you provided does not seem to work on my case and a simple "find -empty" does nothing. On the other end if I have to open each and everyone to read it, this is computational intensive. Thank you for the link though I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a partial answer. If we suppose that a txt file with an empty content has at least one hidden character, then someone can find all files with size under a specific number of bytes and delete these. If for example we would like to delete all files of size 1 byte we can issue:

```
find . -type f -size -2c -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

The truly empty files will show 0 bytes, when looked at with `ls -l`.

You can remove them with `find` (read `man find` https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/find.1.html):

```
find folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -size 0 -delete
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however the files that I have do not show size 0 but size 4kb. When I open them there is no content but probably some hidden characters.

Comment: Try running `od -bc` on one of the files. Or, use `/bin/ls -l`. Even a zero-byte file uses a 4K disk block, so that a write to it won't fail due to disk full. You're confused about the difference between "data in file (0 bytes)" and "filesystem space allocated".